# Redirect output of process ran by execv

Tags: c++, linux, execv, dev-null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirecting output to a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516823/redirecting-output-to-a-file-in-c)

I'm running a process as follows:

```
char* [NUM];
char[0] = processName;
char[1] = arg0;
...
char[NUM] = 0;
execv(args[0],args);
```

The question is how I can make it redirect its output to

```
/dev/null
```

I tried adding it to the args array but it sent it as arguments to the program...

Any idea anyone?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12764581/85371 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the target you want, then close the `fd` you want to
reassign, use `dup2` to connect it there, and close the previous open:

```
int tmpFd = open( "/dev/null", O_WRONLY );
if ( tmpFd == -1 ) {
    //  Real problem, couldn't open /dev/null
}
if ( dup2( tmpFd, 1 ) ) != 1 ) {
    //  Real problem, dup2 failed.
}
close( tmpFd );
```